# Trying to post date in UTC format in json but it is converting : to %3A . How

Tags: json, date, formatting, http-post

Trying to post date in UTC format in json but it is converting : to %3A .

Example:

```
{"date:"2016-09-05T16:15:30.623Z"}
```

in UTC format but it is

```
2016-09-05T16%3A14%3A11.623Z
```

Please help how to avoid this at time of post date in

```
content-type:'application/json'
```

Date is getting from system current date

Thanks:)

Comment: How are you sending the data? Where does the date come from?

Comment: system current date

Comment: Please post the actual source code.

Comment: data = {date': '' }fetchData = function() {
          var tempDateTime = new Date();
          data.date = tempDateTime.toJSON();
            promise = $http({   method: 'post',  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8','Accept': 'application/json' },ransformRequest: function(obj) {
                    var str = []; for (var p in obj)str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p])); return str.join("&");},             data: data,
                url: url